# How to scan a barcode with all available back cameras of an iphone at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avcapturedevice

What I want:
I want to scan for barcodes with all available back cameras of an iPhone **at the same time**. So the user don't have to care about the distance of the barcode so much.

What I tried:

1. I created an `AVCaptureSession` for each camera, and used one camera for the `videoPreviewLayer` so that the user can see a live video of one camera. The problem here is that if I start more than one `AVCaptureSession`, the live video will freeze.

   ```swift
   func setupCaptureSessions() {
       let devices = [ AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: codeScanningDevicesTypes, mediaType: .video, position: .back).devices.first!,
                       AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: codeScanningDevicesTypes, mediaType: .video, position: .back).devices.last! ]

       for device in devices {
           let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
           captureSession.beginConfiguration()

           guard let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) else {
               print("Failed to create device input for camera")
               return
           }

           guard captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) else {
               print("Failed to add device input to capture session")
               return
           }

           captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)

           let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
           if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
               captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

               metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
               metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
           }

           captureSession.commitConfiguration()
           captureSessions.append(captureSession)
       }
   }

   func startScanning() {


       // Video Konfiguration
       let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
       videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

       guard let captureSession = captureSessions.first else { return }

       if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
           videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "video_ouput_queue"))
           captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
       }


       videoPreviewLayer.session = captureSession
       videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
       videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation()

       for captureSession in captureSessions {
           captureSession.startRunning()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Another try was to use an `AVCaptureMultiCamSession` and just to create a bunch of `AVCaptureDeviceInput` and at them to the `captureSession`. The problem here is that just one camera was really scanning for barcodes:

   ```swift
   let codeScanningDevicesTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType] = [
       .builtInUltraWideCamera,
       .builtInDualWideCamera,
       .builtInWideAngleCamera,
       .builtInTripleCamera,
       .builtInDualCamera,
       .builtInTelephotoCamera,
   ]

   private let allDetactableCodeTypes = [
       AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39,
       .code39Mod43,
       .code93,
       .code128,
       .ean8,
       .ean13,
       .interleaved2of5,
       .itf14,
       .upce,
       .aztec,
       .dataMatrix,
       .pdf417,
       .qr
   ]

   private func setupCaptureSession() {

       defer {
           captureDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
           captureSession.commitConfiguration()
       }

       guard let device = captureDevice else {
           return
       }

       let backCameras:[AVCaptureDevice] = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: codeScanningDevicesTypes, mediaType: .video, position: .back).devices

       captureSession.beginConfiguration()

       // Inputs:

       backCameras.forEach { device in

           guard let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) else {
               return
           }

           if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
               captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
           }

           do {
               try configureDevice(device: device)
           } catch {
               let error = ImageScannerControllerError.inputDevice
               delegate?.captureSessionManager(self, didFailWithError: error)
               return
           }
       }


       // Outputs:
       let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

       if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
           captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
           metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
           metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = allDetactableCodeTypes
       }

       let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
       videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

       if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
           videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "video_ouput_queue"))
           captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
       }

       videoPreviewLayer.session = captureSession
       videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
       videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation()
   }
   ```

So the question now, how is it possible to scan for barcodes with all available cameras at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution for myself, maybe it can help someone with the same Problem:

```
    private let videoPreviewLayerView: UIView
    private let videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    
  private lazy var dualVideoSession: AVCaptureMultiCamSession = {
      AVCaptureMultiCamSession()
    }()
    let dualVideoSessionOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "dual video session data output queue")

     private func configurCodeScanningDevice() {
    
        dualVideoSession.beginConfiguration()
        defer {
          dualVideoSession.commitConfiguration()
            dualVideoSession.startRunning()
        }
        
        videoPreviewLayer.setSessionWithNoConnection(dualVideoSession)
        videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        let ultraWideCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInUltraWideCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        let wideCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        let cameras = [wideCamera, ultraWideCamera].compactMap{ $0 }
        
        guard !cameras.isEmpty else { return }
        
        for (index, camera) in cameras.enumerated() {
          
          guard let deviceInput = createInputAndAddToSession(device: camera),
                let videoInputPort = createVideoPort(deviceInput: deviceInput, device: camera),
                let videoDataOuput = createVideoDataOutputAndAddToSession(),
                configureDevice(device: camera) == true
          else {
            continue
          }
          
          _ = createConnection(inputPort: videoInputPort, videoDataOutput: videoDataOuput)
          
          if index == 0 {
            createLayerConnection(videoInputPort: videoInputPort)
          }
          createMetadataOutput()
        }
        
        // For Debugging:
    //    printAllSessionConnections()
      }
      
      private func printAllSessionConnections() {
            dualVideoSession.connections.forEach { connection in
              print(connection)
              print("\n")
            }
      }
      
      private func createMetadataOutput() {
        // NOTE: The order is important: addOutput must be called before setMetadataObjectTypes
        captureMetadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        dualVideoSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = codeDetectionConfig.detectableCodeTypes.isEmpty ? allDetactableCodeTypes : codeDetectionConfig.detectableCodeTypes
      }
      
      private func createLayerConnection(videoInputPort: AVCaptureInput.Port) {
    
        let frontLayerConnection = AVCaptureConnection(inputPort: videoInputPort, videoPreviewLayer: videoPreviewLayer)
        guard dualVideoSession.canAddConnection(frontLayerConnection) else {
            print("no connection to front layer")
            return
        }
        dualVideoSession.addConnection(frontLayerConnection)
        frontLayerConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
        frontLayerConnection.isVideoMirrored = false
        frontLayerConnection.videoOrientation = videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation()
      }
      
      private func createInputAndAddToSession(device: AVCaptureDevice) -> AVCaptureDeviceInput? {
        guard let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device),
                dualVideoSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) else {
            print("no camera input")
            return nil
        }
        dualVideoSession.addInputWithNoConnections(deviceInput)
        return deviceInput
      }
      
      private func createVideoPort(deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput, device: AVCaptureDevice) -> AVCaptureInput.Port? {
        // search front video port for dual video session
        guard let videoPort = deviceInput.ports(for: .video, sourceDeviceType: device.deviceType, sourceDevicePosition: device.position).first else {
            print("no front camera device input's video port")
            return nil
        }
        
        return videoPort
      }
      
      private func createVideoDataOutputAndAddToSession() -> AVCaptureVideoDataOutput? {
        let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        guard dualVideoSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) else {
            print("no back camera output")
            return nil
        }
        dualVideoSession.addOutputWithNoConnections(videoDataOutput)
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dualVideoSessionOutputQueue)
        
        return videoDataOutput
      }
      
      private func createConnection(inputPort: AVCaptureInput.Port, videoDataOutput: AVCaptureOutput) -> Bool {
        // connect front output to dual video session
        let frontOutputConnection = AVCaptureConnection(inputPorts: [inputPort], output: videoDataOutput)
        guard dualVideoSession.canAddConnection(frontOutputConnection) else {
            print("no connection to the front video output")
            return false
        }
        dualVideoSession.addConnection(frontOutputConnection)
        frontOutputConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
        frontOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
        frontOutputConnection.isVideoMirrored = true
        
        return true
      }
```